# VB6-- Premission denied when Writing to file

Tags: text, file-io, vb6

I have got the "Permission Denied" when i Opened my file to write somethings in it.

> ```
>     Dim CustomDriveIcon As String
>     CustomDriveIcon = "CustomDriveIcon_" & txtDrive.Text & ".reg"
>      Dim newFIle
>      Dim FSO
>      Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>      Set newFIle = FSO.CreateTextFile(CustomDriveIcon)
> ```
>
> DoEvents

```
Dim sFileText As String
Dim iFileNo As Integer
  iFileNo = FreeFile
Open CustomDriveIcon For Output As #iFileNo
 Print #iFileNo, "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00"
 Print #iFileNo, ""
 Print #iFileNo, "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\C\DefaultIcon]"
 Print #iFileNo, "@=" & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & txtIconPath & "\" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) '@="\"C\""
Close #iFileNo
```

And I get the error on line "`Open CustomDriveIcon For Output As #iFileNo`" whats the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've opened the file twice, once with CreateTextFile and once with the Open statement. You can't open the file twice, so it fails on the second time.

Just delete these lines - you don't need them.

```
Dim newFIle Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystem Object") 
Set newFIle = FSO.CreateTextFile(CustomDriveIcon )
```

Comment: but i want to make the File !

Comment: The file will be created by the Open For Output. You don't need the FileSystemObject code